# Disabling Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have a web app that uses Google Maps (via JavaScript). When a user presses a button, I want to prevent the user from interacting with the map and provide an overlay that says "loading...". I'm not sure how to do this via JavaScript. Currently, I have the following:

```
<button class="btn btn-info" onclick="loadData();">Load</button>
<div id="myMap" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var myMap = null;
    $(function () {
        var options = { zoom: 14), center: maploc, mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROAD };
        myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myMap"), options);    
    });

    function loadData() {

    }
</script>
```

I'm not sure how to tackle my situation with the map.

Comment: Just put a semi transparent div over your map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add an overlay div in your HTML file, when your function is called you set the div's display to block, when your data is finished loading, you can set the display to none.(or set the visibility of the element to `hidden` or `visible`)

sample:

```
  <body>
    <div id="overlay"></div>
  </body>
```

You can see this JSFiddle for more detail:
https://jsfiddle.net/pdvdyh79/

**Edited**:
Or you can see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/pdvdyh79/2/, it shows an overlay when a window is loaded (`visibility` equals to `visible`), and hide the overlay when the map is done loading in the callback function. (`visibility` set to `hidden`).